# FOS UserBundle access controll doesn't work

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, access-control

I have FOS UserBundle installed in my symfony2 project. Login/logout works, only problem is, the system doesn't redirect/close parts that i want closed.
The whole site should only be accessable by loged in users.
Yet i can call any route.

I filled in the data in the access control section of my security yml, yet it doesn't work. I can call mydomain/de_CH/anything/i/want/ and access that content.

This is my security.yml:

```
security:
  providers:
    fos_userbundle:
      id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

  encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

  firewalls:
    main:
      pattern: ^/
      form_login:
        provider: fos_userbundle
        login_path: fos_user_security_login 
        check_path: fos_user_security_check
        csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
      logout:
        path:   fos_user_security_logout
      anonymous:    true

  access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/my-admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/$, role: ROLE_USER }
    #- { path: ^/$, role: ROLE_USER }

  role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

Comment: stupid question, but have you tried accessing a page in a new incognito browser window? You might have a session cookie lying around

Comment: @Jaitsu: Nope. Good guess still.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
- { path: ^/$, role: ROLE_USER }
```

to

```
 - { path: ^/.*, role: ROLE_USER }
```

This is because, first regex tell you allow `ROLE_USER` to path with that pattern `/`
So, patterns like `/foo` `/foo/bar` and so on aren't catched from your firewall.

Second pattern cover the latter case

Comment: This did lead to a redirect loop :(

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `anonymous:    true` part and put `/login` to it's own firewall so users can log in.
The `anonymous` part allowed anonymous user to access that firewall.

```
firewalls:
    login_firewall:
        pattern:    ^/login$
        anonymous:  ~
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            # ...
        logout:
            path:   fos_user_security_logout
```

**EDIT:** Since we denied anonymous users access to the page, we need to create separate firewall for `/login` otherwise they wouldn't be able to log in.
See section "Avoid Common Pitfalls" in the official documentation:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html for more info on the subject.

Comment: Login is already accessible by all user. Look at `access_control` section

Comment: if you disable anonymous users, it wont't be

Comment: `anonymous: true` ... Anonymous isn't disabled

Comment: Read my whole post. In solution I suggest it is in `main` firewall.

Comment: ok, my bad. But this isn't the right solution. OP says that login/logout works

Comment: Ok, login works, but anybody can access his whole site anyway. 

So by restricting anonymous users from accessing it, that problem is solved. But then no one can access the login page either, so it has to be in it's own firewall so user, that is not logged in, can access login page.

Comment: mine answer is the correct one, trust me, i've implemented it in my applications and it works like a charm ;-)

Comment: I'm not saying your way doesn't work. I'm saying my solution is cleaner in sense of strictly separating not authenticated area form secured area. It's also slightly more efficient, since there are less checks needed - with your approach in each request the security component ensures, the user is not anonymous.

Comment: @tomas.pecserke: i get a redirect loop with your solution as well :(

Comment: I just noticed, you put route names in configuration instead of paths.
Replace `login_path: fos_user_security_login` with `login_path: /login` and `check_path: fos_user_security_check` with `check_path: /login_check`.